# Store simple application data on Android

Tags: android

My activity allows the user to select multiple folders. I would like to store this selection in order to be able to recreate it later (ie. mark folders as selected when the activity is started again). What's the best approach to do this? I'm thinking of using Shared Preferences or Internal Storage (write a file with paths list when activity finishes and read this file on activity start).

Comment: Welcome to the Stackoverflow. Let me take an opportunity to guide you,  while posting thread, make sure to include possible code that you have tried, logcat output if any issue, R&D you have done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User `SharedPreferences`:

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
Editor editor = sp.edit();
editor.putStringSet("selectedFolders", selectedFolders);
editor.commit();
```

to get it later:

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
Set<String> selectedFolders = sp.getStringSet("selectedFolders", new HashSet<String>()):
```

Comment: I wasn't really asking about the code, more about the best approach. Thanks nonetheless!

Comment: best approach is to use `SharedPreference` in this scenario.